# Overflow and other menu items not displayed on Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-toolbar, android-menu

I am currently trying to add a toolbar as the action bar and I am having trouble getting anything besides the name of the app to display. I am adding the Toolbar from appcompat and have created the menu xml file. Is there a necessary step I need to take in order to link the two?

Here is my activity xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".canvas.CanvasActivity"
    >


    <com.alastech.andyluo.crowdshout_androidapp.canvas.CanvasTest
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/canvas_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I am sure the toolbar is being added to the layout correctly because I have been able to change its size and that has been reflected correctly when it runs.

Here is the xml for the menu:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_new_shout"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp"
       android:title="@string/action_new_shout"
       app:showAsAction="always"
        />



    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu"
        android:title="@string/action_menu"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        />

</menu>
```

And this is the only thing that shows up in the action bar:

[image]

Just to be clear I am pretty much following this tutorial exactly:
http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: is that an activity or fragment?

Comment: did u set setHasOptionMenu(true); if u are using a fragment

Comment: This is for an activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below method in you activity

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // use sample_actions or wheever your xml for the menufile name below
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sample_actions, menu);
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Interesting, I saw a similar solution for this earlier and tried it with no success. This works perfectly! Thank you!